# Reassigning one-to-one relationship nulls previous object / CoreData iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship, nsmanagedobject

I have 2 entities. ObjectA stores all ObjectB's objects through a many-to-many relationship. ObjectA also stores one specific object as a default object using a one-to-one relationship. The idea is to be able to assign many different child objects for EntityA while also keeping a specific reference to one specific child object. This idea works perfectly fine all throughout my project exempt in one circumstance(identical code and identical entity relationship setups.

The problem I am having is when I reassign the existing defaultObject to a new different object by simply `ObjectA.defaultObject = someObject23;` this assigns the new object correctly but in the process my original To-Many relationship reference to that existing defaultObject goes null.

The to-many relationship 'AllObjects' from EntityA has a Cascade delete rule for EntityB. 
The One-To-One relationship 'DefaultObject' has a NULL delete rule for EntityB.
Both have inverses set.

Here is a real quick overview.

```
ObjectA.allObjects = 10 objects; // 1 of these is someObject1

ObjectA.defaultSomeObject = someObject1; // This works fine.
ObjectA.defaultSomeObject = someObject2; // This assigns the new defaultSomeObject=someObject2,
// but in the process it removes the someObject1 from my ObjectA.allObjects array (Goes NULL)
```

I'm stumped because like I say I have used this technique multiple times and the only workaround to this I have succeeded with is to "rig" it and actually save a reference to the previous object, delete it from the ObjectA array, set the new defaultObject, then write that object back to the array. There must be a simple explanation I am overlooking. More coffee? lol. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have tried all the different delete rules for each relationship as well just for kicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Definitely needed more coffee. What was happening was the one-to-one relationship was using the to-many relationship inverse causing it to do exactly what it was supposed to do, go null...